# Import a column of data, make a matrix from it and export it WITHOUT curly braces

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import

I'm new here and with *Mathematica*, too. I want *Mathematica* to import data from a txt file (it has one column of data). These entries are z-values. From this I want to make a matrix - 508 entries make one row, 308 rows in total. And then I want to export it to a dat file.

Here is my code:

```
data = Import["D:\\Data\\Mathematica\\Convert_data\\rawdata.txt", "Table"]; Flatten[data];
carray = ConstantArray[1, {308, 508}];
For[j = 1, j < 309, j++, 
  For[i = 1, i < 508, i++, carray[[j, i]] = data[[(j - 1)*508 + i]] ]
];
Export["test.dat", carray, "Table"]
```

It does nearly everything it is supposed to do. It creates a matrix as I want it to, but all the entries are in curly braces. I think the problem is right at the beginning, when I import the data, all the entries are in a curly brace, and all these braces are within a common brace. I tried to get rid of the single curly braces around each value with "Flatten", but it doesn't do anything.

The txt file I start with looks like this:

```
1.598669e+000   
1.570571e+000   
1.600274e+000   
1.513271e+000   
1.549999e+000   
1.426268e+000   
1.197772e+000
....
```

It has many entries, so I don't show all of them here.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your data, for example at a site like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), so others can download it and test possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, dionys. And here is the file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=46674322808024643081

Comment: FYI your `Flatten[data]` does nothing. (It creates a flat version of `data` and discards it).  You would need `data=Flatten[data]` to do what you probably though you were doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the data in the text file has one column, importing using the [`"Table"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) format produces a nested N × 1 array, where N is the number of lines in the file. Instead, use the [`"List"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/List.html) import format, and you will get a one-dimensional array:

```
Import["D:/Data/Mathematica/Convert_data/rawdata.txt", "List"]
```

should give `{1.59867, 1.57057, 1.60027, 1.51327, 1.55, 1.42627, 1.19777, ...}`. The rest of your code should then work as expected, except the condition in the `For` loop over `i` should be `i < 509`.

**But** it's almost always better to use built-in functions, [rather than loops](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica). You can use the function [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) to split your list into a nested 308 × 508 array:

```
Export["test.dat", Partition[Import["D:/Data/Mathematica/Convert_data/rawdata.txt", "List"], 508], "Table"];
```

---

Here's an example using `ImportString` and `ExportString` instead:

```
ExportString[Partition[ImportString["1.598669e+000
    1.570571e+000
    1.600274e+000
    1.513271e+000
    1.549999e+000
    1.426268e+000
    1.197772e+000
    1.197772e+001", "List"], 4], "Table"]
```

Comment: Instead of curly braces I have no this quotation signs "". One quotation sign before the value then the second quotation sign that occupies a matrix element for itself and so one.

Comment: I think the problem is that your data file (thanks for providing it) has spaces after the numbers on each line. The simplest fix seems to be to use `First/@Import[..., "Table"]` instead of `Import[..., "List"]`.

Comment: Both your suggestions (First/@Import[..., "Table"] and Import[..., "List"]) yield the same result for me. Both with the quotation signs.

Comment: Using your data file, `Export["test.dat", Partition[First /@ Import["rawdata.txt", "Table"], 508], "Table"];` gives me a TSV file with just the numbers and no quotation marks. Could you try `Import["rawdata.txt", "Table"] // First // InputForm` and tell me what the output is?

Comment: If you don't need Mathematica to interpret the input as numbers, just to reformat the contents of the file, you could instead use `Export["test.dat", StringJoin @@@ Partition[Import["rawdata.txt", "Lines"], 508], "Lines"];`. The format specifier `"Lines"` instructs Mathematica to treat the contents of the file as strings, and `StringJoin` combines the columns of the resulting array.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen, this one worked:Export["test.dat", 
 StringJoin @@@ 
  Partition[
   Import["D:\\Data\\Mathematica\\Convert_data\\rawdata.txt", 
    "Lines"], 508], "Lines"]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
(* Import your data as tab-separated values; extra "" will be included *)
Import["c:\\Users\\Marco\\Desktop\\Sandbox\\rawdata.txt", "TSV"];
Flatten[%];

(* remove the "" caused by the extra tabs in your data file *)
DeleteCases[%, ""];

(* Reshape your data into an array with your required dimensions *)
ArrayReshape[%, {308, 508}];

(* Export the reshaped array to a *.DAT files *)
Export["data.dat", %]
```